# Why is this question asking about dealing with the after math of office harrasment being downvoted?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

[Is it best to move on after being harassed at work?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/47178/is-it-best-to-move-on-after-being-harassed-at-work)

Clearly the OP is an emotionally frazzled state, but I think The Workplace as a culture doesn't appreciate that this is actually a normal course of events for working in an office environments.

People are going to have inter-personal and intra-personal problems.

It seems like people are seeing this saga play out, and are downvoting it because they don't like the OPs emotional response.

But the question itself is pretty objective, and IMO to which the answer is pretty clear - "Yes, sometimes it is best to move on".

Comment: Have you looked at the questions asked by the OP? We've been answering pretty much the same question for (at least) the past the months, and I think people are just getting a bit fed up of it.

Comment: It is soothing to rant about your colleagues on the internet, but unfortunately it doesn't solve your problem. It was high time OP took control of her life and moved on. Posting the same question here every week doesnt help anyone, not her, not the ones answering the questions, not the future readers. She has been told this multiple times by multiple people. I hope she gets the message now and decides to stop suffering.

Comment: @PhilipKendall if the questions asked are duplicates, then they should just be closed as duplicate.
Also, looking at her post history, I can't see that she's asking the same questions over and over. Clearly she has difficulty with her place, but she's asking questions regarding different aspects of it.

Answer (score 7):

Downvoting is by default anonymous. People can downvote for whatever reason they want, whether it's because they are annoyed, misclick the down arrow (I've done this a few times...), or just because.

But here are a few possibilities I could see as reasons it's been downvoted:

- As [Philip Kendall said](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3180/why-is-this-question-asking-about-dealing-with-the-after-math-of-office-harrasme#comment7251_3180), there have been a lot of similar questions from this user
- There are at least two, very different questions being asked
- "what should I do?" is not a practically answerable question
- It reads not like a practical question but more like, "woe is me, my life is miserable" and an [Agony Aunt](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1828/2322) type question