# Personal Advice

Tags: discussion, site-policy

I'm noticing a significant number of questions (e.g. [this one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13727/should-i-get-another-bsc-degree-in-order-to-have-better-work-prospects) and [this one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13722/nothing-to-show-for-the-past-several-months-at-work)) that seem to be asking for advice so tailored to the questioners situation that they are essentially personal advice. Other sites in StackExchange (e.g. Christianity) tend to forbid those questions.

Should we forbid them also?

(P.S. if you don't think the questions I linked to are really that personal, feel free to answer this and indicate how personal they should get before they are closed - if at all)

Answer (score 4):

I went ahead and put the first question on hold because we really can't tell the asker whether or not he should get a CS degree; however, I left the second question because it describes a problem in the workplace.

The only suggestion I have for the second question is to edit it a bit to focus on a more definitive question at the end than "What should I do", which would make it a better question. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Here are [my thoughts](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1720/can-we-add-questions-asking-for-advice-to-the-list-of-off-topic-questions), more or less.

I typically vote to close questions which are, "tell me what to do" that don't have a clearly defined question other than that.